# Image field not supporting bmp images

Tags: entities, nodes, media

Why is the image field in Drupal 7 CCK not supporting a bmp file extension? When I add this format in the field "Allowed file extensions" list, it saves, but never show it in the form and does not let me upload a bmp file also.

Is it a natural occurance? Is there anything I can do about this?

Thanks.

Comment: BMP files are not compressed. Most browsers will rather let you download them, than display. Why do you want to use so web-unfriendly format? GIF, JPG and PNG should be enough for most situations. SVG sometimes, for vector. Any other is not safe for web now.

Comment: See [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1051056) - seems bmp is problematic since 6.x and it's not going to change.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Actually my client has some bmp images he wants to upload and I never tried uploading one in past. Which was why I was doubtful whether this was an issue with my installation, or was this a general problem.

Comment: There are ways to make it possible (or so I've heard), but I never did it and I advise against even trying. Storing bmp files as files? OK. As images? Not so, if site will try to display them, things may break for your reader.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity I created a file field and uploaded a bmp file. Having file entity installed I set its display mode to default, and the file:image File display mode to image with image style. It displayed fine but only when the format was set as original image. I then tried imagecache's 'Change file format Convert to: jpg' It changes the file format but not the extension. The browser did not want to display the converted image.

Comment: Hmm, so the image styling/resizings does not work with this converted image?